# Android: how to find height of ContentView after rotation?

Tags: android

I am trying to find the height of my content view after device rotation.  The below code prints ContentView.bottom on startup and after rotation.  If I start my device in portrait mode, rotate to landscape mode, and rotate back to portrait mode it prints: 989,989,565.  The initial 989 is correct, the other two numbers are wrong, they are the size for the ContnetView prior to the rotation.

Is there a way to detect that the layout changes due to rotation are finished, prior to printing the size of the ContentVew?

The activity sets this flag:

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"  

public class TempProjActivity extends Activity 
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        printContentBottom();

    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
    {
        //this occurs when device is rotated or keyboard is exposed/hidden
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        printContentBottom();
    }

    private void printContentBottom()
    {
        getWindow().findViewById(Window.ID_ANDROID_CONTENT).post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                Log.e("", getWindow().findViewById(Window.ID_ANDROID_CONTENT).getBottom()+"");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: if you are developing for API 13 and above, you might need to use `"keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"`

Comment: sorry, this is for <= API 10.

Comment: May I ask why exactly you came across this problem? Is there something bigger you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm just trying to understand the context of your question :)

Comment: Well, my issue would be solved so simply if I could ensure that on size change due to rotation, my code does not execute until the size change has finished...  Expounding the details of the situation and alternative strategies, would be less simple